# how to move sprite object using AndEngine (Android)

Tags: android, andengine

I am using andengine to develop a game in android. I placed an object in sprite like

```
 this.mTexture = new Texture(32, 32, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
            this.mFaceTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTexture, this, "gfx/bike.png", 0, 0);
---- and i place like 
Sprite bikeSprite= new Sprite(20, 50, this.mFaceTextureRegion);
```

I want to use this sprite in j2me sprite

`bikeSprite.move(--);` How do I do it in android. I dont want to use setPosition .

Comment: just put a move modifier. giving you an example in below

Comment: It's a pity that the author of the engine removed Shape.setVelocity() in the new version of the Engine. Now you have to use modifiers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class EntityModifierExample extends BaseExample {
    // ===========================================================
    // Constants
    // ===========================================================

    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    private Camera mCamera;
    private Texture mTexture;
    private TiledTextureRegion mFaceTextureRegion;

    // ===========================================================
    // Constructors
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Getter & Setter
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
    // ===========================================================

    @Override
    public Engine onLoadEngine() {
        this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResources() {
        this.mTexture = new Texture(64, 32, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        this.mFaceTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mTexture, this, "gfx/face_box_tiled.png", 0, 0, 2, 1);

        this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mTexture);
    }

    @Override
    public Scene onLoadScene() {
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

        final Scene scene = new Scene();
        scene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));

        final int centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
        final int centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;

        final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(centerX + 100, centerY, 32, 32);
        rect.setColor(1, 0, 0);

        final AnimatedSprite face = new AnimatedSprite(centerX - 100, centerY, this.mFaceTextureRegion);
        face.animate(100);
        face.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        final LoopEntityModifier entityModifier =
            new LoopEntityModifier(
                    new IEntityModifierListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onModifierStarted(final IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, final IEntity pItem) {
                            EntityModifierExample.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(EntityModifierExample.this, "Sequence started.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onModifierFinished(final IModifier<IEntity> pEntityModifier, final IEntity pEntity) {
                            EntityModifierExample.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(EntityModifierExample.this, "Sequence finished.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    1,
                    new ILoopEntityModifierListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoopStarted(final LoopModifier<IEntity> pLoopModifier, final int pLoop, final int pLoopCount) {
                            EntityModifierExample.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(EntityModifierExample.this, "Loop: '" + (pLoop + 1) + "' of '" + pLoopCount + "' started.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoopFinished(final LoopModifier<IEntity> pLoopModifier, final int pLoop, final int pLoopCount) {
                            EntityModifierExample.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(EntityModifierExample.this, "Loop: '" + (pLoop + 1) + "' of '" + pLoopCount + "' finished.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    new SequenceEntityModifier(
                            new RotationModifier(1, 0, 90),
                            new AlphaModifier(2, 1, 0),
                            new AlphaModifier(1, 0, 1),
                            new ScaleModifier(2, 1, 0.5f),
                            new DelayModifier(0.5f),
                            new ParallelEntityModifier(
                                    new ScaleModifier(3, 0.5f, 5),
                                    new RotationByModifier(3, 90)
                            ),
                            new ParallelEntityModifier(
                                    new ScaleModifier(3, 5, 1),
                                    new RotationModifier(3, 180, 0)
                            )
                    )
            );

        face.registerEntityModifier(entityModifier);
        rect.registerEntityModifier(entityModifier.clone());

        scene.attachChild(face);
        scene.attachChild(rect);

        return scene;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete() {

    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Inner and Anonymous Classes
    // ===========================================================
}
```

This code is extracted from the [samples project Andengine](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/). [Reference to the original code](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/EntityModifierExample.java).

Answer (score 2):

I would try using a PathModifier. I have this same problem for my game, and a PathModifier example can be found in the AndEngine examples:

```
package org.anddev.andengine.examples;

import org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions.ScreenOrientation;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.IEntity;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.modifier.LoopEntityModifier;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.modifier.PathModifier;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.modifier.PathModifier.IPathModifierListener;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.modifier.PathModifier.Path;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.background.RepeatingSpriteBackground;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite.AnimatedSprite;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegionFactory;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TiledTextureRegion;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.source.AssetTextureSource;
import org.anddev.andengine.util.Debug;
import org.anddev.andengine.util.modifier.ease.EaseSineInOut;

import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * @author Nicolas Gramlich
 * @since 11:54:51 - 03.04.2010
 */
public class PathModifierExample extends BaseExample {
    // ===========================================================
    // Constants
    // ===========================================================

    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    private Camera mCamera;

    private RepeatingSpriteBackground mGrassBackground;

    private Texture mTexture;
    private TiledTextureRegion mPlayerTextureRegion;

    // ===========================================================
    // Constructors
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Getter & Setter
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
    // ===========================================================

    @Override
    public Engine onLoadEngine() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You move my sprite right round, right round...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResources() {
        this.mTexture = new Texture(128, 128, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
        this.mPlayerTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mTexture, this, "gfx/player.png", 0, 0, 3, 4);

        this.mGrassBackground = new RepeatingSpriteBackground(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT, this.mEngine.getTextureManager(), new AssetTextureSource(this, "gfx/background_grass.png"));

        this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mTexture);
    }

    @Override
    public Scene onLoadScene() {
//      this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

        final Scene scene = new Scene();
        scene.setBackground(this.mGrassBackground);

        /* Create the face and add it to the scene. */
        final AnimatedSprite player = new AnimatedSprite(10, 10, 48, 64, this.mPlayerTextureRegion);

        final Path path = new Path(5).to(10, 10).to(10, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 74).to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 58, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 74).to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 58, 10).to(10, 10);

        /* Add the proper animation when a waypoint of the path is passed. */
        player.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(new PathModifier(30, path, null, new IPathModifierListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPathStarted(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity) {
                Debug.d("onPathStarted");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPathWaypointStarted(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity, final int pWaypointIndex) {
                Debug.d("onPathWaypointStarted:  " + pWaypointIndex);
                switch(pWaypointIndex) {
                    case 0:
                        player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 6, 8, true);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 3, 5, true);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 0, 2, true);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 9, 11, true);
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPathWaypointFinished(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity, final int pWaypointIndex) {
                Debug.d("onPathWaypointFinished: " + pWaypointIndex);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPathFinished(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity) {
                Debug.d("onPathFinished");
            }
        }, EaseSineInOut.getInstance())));
        scene.attachChild(player);

        return scene;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete() {

    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Inner and Anonymous Classes
    // ===========================================================
}
```