# Making a sprite jump when user taps on the screen?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am using andengine to implement a sprite being able to be dragged across the screen using this.

So what i want to do is when the user taps any where on the screen make the sprite jump.

or move up and then move down.

What is the best way to go bout doing this with andengine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
    if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) { //Jump only if the user tapped, not moved his finger or something
        final Entity playerEntity = ...;//Get player entity here.

        final float jumpDuration = 2;
        final float startX = playerEntity.getX();
        final float jumpHeight = 100;

        final MoveYModifier moveUpModifier = new MoveYModifier(jumpDuration / 2, startX, startX - jumpHeight); // - since we want the sprite to go up.
        final MoveYModifier moveDownModifier = new MoveYModifier(jumpDuration / 2, startX + jumpHeight, startX);
        final SequenceEntityModifier modifier = new SequenceEntityModifier(moveUpModifier, moveDownModifier);

        playerEntity.registerEntityModifier(modifier);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Keep in mind that, if you will use this, whenever there is an `ACTION_DOWN` event, you might miss some other event handlers for this (For example, if you have on-screen buttons, they will never handle the event).

The way to handle it is to use add any other entities you want to receive touch events as touch areas for your scene, `Scene.registerTouchArea(ITouchArea)` does so. `Sprite`s and `AnimatedSprite`s implement `ITouchArea`, so you can use these.

When a `Scene` receives a `TouchEvent` to handle, it will first let all the `ITouchArea`s you registered handle it, then if non of them consumed it, it will try the `onSceneTouchEvenet` method.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you would have to set up a listener shown how in this tutorial: http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/updating-sprites-objects-listeners-t386.html then perhaps use a move modifier as shown in this post:
[how to move sprite object using AndEngine (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692862/how-to-move-sprite-object-using-andengine-android)
I hope that you will figure out your problem. ;)

Good Luck- Lijap

Comment: Thanks, but im actually already doing this for the sprite, but now i want it to "Jump" anytime the user taps the screen when not touching the sprite.

Comment: Sorry, I have pretty limited knowlege on andengine, I believe that Jong's answer will be sufficient.